# MSDTC.exe listening on port 5357 but DCOM port range restricted to 5000-5020

Tags: msdtc

I've been having problems trying to get DTCPing.exe to work between 2 servers. I read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx#TheRpcServerisUnavailable) article and tried to troubleshoot the issue.

One of the suggestions to to run netstat -anob to determine what port DTCPIng.exe or msdtc.exe was listening on. When I run the command it says it's listening on port 5357, even though I have restricted the DCOM port range to 5000-5020 on both machines. (I have rebooted both machines, and my system admin says the firewall is open bidirectionally for ports 135, and the range 5000-5020)

Am I missing something? Shouldn't msdtc.exe be listening between the DCOM port range and not on port 5357?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. The port ranges were being exhausted as quite a few RPC calls were taking place. We increased the DCOM port range to 5000-5300 and that then started to work. However every server that participates in the DTC transaction would need identical port ranges and the firewall's would also need to allow the ranges bidirectionally.